# foreach statement overload in d programing language

Tags: foreach, d

Hello I would like to define my own class collection, and make it iterable in a foreach statement, just like this :

```
public class Collection(Type)
{
    ...
    private T head;
    private Collection!(T) queue;
}

Collection!(int) temp;
foreach (int t; temp) { ... }
```

What methods should I define, and how ?

Answer (score 9):

you can specify the `front`, `popfront()` and `empty` functions: (but this will consume your collection unless you use save())

```
public class Collection(T) { ... private T head;  private Collection!(T) queue;

    @property T front(){
        return head;
    }

    @property bool empty(){
        return queue is null;
    }

    void popfront(){
        head = queue.head;
        queue = queue.queue;
    }

    Collection!T save(){
        return new Collection!T(head,queue);
    }

}
```

or use a dedicated struct for iteration (as is done in the `std.container` module

```
public class Collection(T) { ... private T head;  private Collection!(T) queue;

    Range opSlice(){
        return Range(head,queue);
    }

    struct Range{
        T h;
        Collection!(T) q;
        this(T he, Collection!(T) qu){
            h=he;
            q=qu;
        }
        @property T front(){
            return h;
        }

        @property bool empty(){
            return q is null;
        }

        void popfront(){
            h = q.head;
            q= q.queue;
        }

        Collection!T save(){
            return this;
        }


    }
}
```

so iteration is done like so

```
Collection!(int) temp; foreach (int t;temp[]) { ... }
```

you also can add an `opApply` for the normal foreach:

```
public int opApply(int delegate(ref T) dg){
    int res=0;
    foreach(ref T;this[]){
        res = dg(t);
        if(res)return res;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Use the dedicated struct. A range is different from a container in that it is consumed when iterated, when iterating a container you don't want to be consuming it. Array's are kind of a hybrid...

Comment: if you don't want it to get consumed use the `save` function so you get a copy that you can consume without affecting the container

Comment: @ratchetfreak It's still bad practice to treat a container like a range. If you pass it to pretty much _any_ range-based function without using `save`, then your container will be consumed. The proper way to do this is implement `opSlice` and have it return a range-type for that container. Having your container implement the range functions is just begging for trouble.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but ranges have save the standard container definition does not have a save function, though dup is similar. http://www.d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_container.html

Comment: @he_the_great Of course containers don't have `save` functions. They're not ranges. The containers' ranges have `save` functions. `dup` and `save` do very different things too. `dup` creates a separate container with separate elements which are equal to what was in the first container but _aren't_ the same elements, whereas `save` returns a range which points to the exact same elements as the first range. Altering those elements alters the elements in both ranges, whereas altering the elements in a `dup`ed container does not alter the elements in the original.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis, The documentation I linked specifically states it does not do a deep copy. But I suppose if the content is value types there would be a differences from range.save and container.dup.

Comment: @he_the_great It's just like `save` and `dup` and arrays. `save` just slices. Any and all changes to the slice affect the original. With `dup`, however, the container and its contents are copied. So, if you change the elements in one container, it does not change the elements in the other. However, copying references types just copies the references. So, if you change the state of an element that is a reference type, of course it'll be affected in both containers. But if you were to reassign an element in one container with a different object, only one would be affected (unlike with a slice).

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this [documentation on ForeachStatements](http://d.digitalmars.com/2.0/statement.html#ForeachStatement) and scroll down a bit.

If I'm reading your example correctly, you could define an `opApply` for `Collection` as follows:

```
public int opApply(int delegate(ref T) dg){

    Collection!T p = this;

    int res = 0;
    while(!res && p !is null){
        res = dg(p.head);
        p = p.queue;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your Collection class should implement opApply. Your foreach body becomes a delegate to an internal for loop, and you iterate over your internal collection (in your case a queue) using a for loop.

Consider the example given in the docs

```
class Foo {
    uint array[2];

    int opApply(int delegate(ref uint) dg)    
    { int result = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            result = dg(array[i]);
            if (result)
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```